# How can I know the length of my current hacking streak for the Sojourner badge?

Tags: achievements, ingress

I want to progress on the Sojourner badge, but my counter got reset at some point. I have started again, but the only value displayed in the badge is the one of my longest streak. So now, until I reach this value again, I am pretty much in the dark regarding where I am on my current streak.

Is there a way to know the value of my current hacking streak (i.e. for how many days I have been able to hack once a day), instead of only my longest streak?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy. Got to the Agent panel, tap on "Now".

"Week" will also work (and show lots more interesting numbers), assuming that your current streak is longer – you should be able to remember that far back …

Comment: Also, you can tap 'now' and it'll tell your current one.